# get final url after redirection

Tags: php, url

I found similar quesitons on the board, but no answer that worked for me ...

my problem is quite simple

when (in my browser, chrome) I go to this url : https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3a%2f%2fsoundcloud.com%2fdubz-cooker%2fdies-irae

I'm automaticly redirected to this url https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/71231482

I'm intrested in getting the ID (last part) of the final url, with php, only having the first link .

any idea on how to do that ?

thanks

Comment: In this particular case, it seems to be Flash that is rewriting it. There is no HTTP redirection going on. You'll have a (very) hard time getting it done in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the url parameter from the first URL and use http instead of https (for some reason it redirects to http)
I.e.

```
 https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3a%2f%2fsoundcloud.com%2fdubz-cooker%2fdies-irae

becomes http://soundcloud.com/dubz-cooker/dies-irae
```

You will then have to use some of PHPs functions to retrieve a URL (file_get_contents, cURL extension, or shell_exec using curl / wget). 
I.e.

```
 <?php 
 $page = file_get_contents('http://soundcloud.com/dubz-cooker/dies-irae');
 preg_match('/"track_id"\:(\d+)/si', $page, $id);
 $id = $id[1];
```

You should now have the track id in $id

Comment: hmmm.. thanks ! I had actually try doing it first in Javascript and was retreiving source with document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]
, and apparently I don't have the same result in PHP, i hadn't tryed that ... shame on me ! thanks !!!

and maybe you know why I can't see that in javascript ?